# sorting with related tables in mysql

Tags: sql-order-by

I cant remember the right aproach in php to sort data from related tables anymore? Iam not sure if its even possible in one query?

```
table brands
id    name
------------
1     Disney
2     Pepsi
3     Sony
```

---

```
table products
id    name        brandId
-----------------------
1     cd-playerX    3
2     nice poster   1
3     usb-radio     3
4     cd-playerY    3
```

I want to list all the products sorted by the **name** of the brand table **(order=asc)** like this:

- nice poster (Disney)
- cd-playerX (Sony)
- cd-playerY (Sony)
- usb-radio (Sony)

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.name + ' (' + b.name + ')' as fullName
from products as p
left join brands as b
     on p.id = b.brandId
order by b.name asc, p.name asc --optional for brands with multiple products
```